# How to calculate $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{4}{x}\big[\frac{x}{3}\big]$

Tags: calculus, limits

> **Question:-Calculate the following limit
> $$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{4}{x}\bigg[\frac{x}{3}\bigg]$$**

**where, [ ] represents greatest integer function.**

There is also a similar limit which can be solved using squeeze theorem as follows
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{3}\bigg[\frac{4}{x}\bigg]$$

As $$x-1< [x] \leq x$$

$$\implies \frac{4}{x} -1< \bigg[\frac{4}{x}\bigg ] \leq \frac{4}{x} $$

$$\implies \frac{x}{3}\bigg(\frac{4}{x} -1\bigg)<\frac{x}{3} \bigg[\frac{4}{x}\bigg ] \leq \frac{x}{3}\bigg(\frac{4}{x}\bigg) $$

**By squeeze theorem, we have**

$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x}{3}\bigg[\frac{4}{x}\bigg]=\frac43$$

But Squeeze theorem is not applicable on the given Limit So How can I do this?

By desmos this limit  also equals $\frac43$

Thank you for your reply

Comment: What's the meaning of the notation $\left[\dfrac 4 3\right]$?

Comment: @Prime Mover Greatest integer function.Sorry, I should have specified that.

Comment: You might want to use the modern notation $\left\lfloor \dfrac 4 3 \right \rfloor$ and call it the "floor function".

Comment: There is also another detail in the example: multiplying by $\frac{x}{3}$ will invert the inequalities if $x<0$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The limit doesn't exists since $$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{4}{x}\left\lfloor\frac{x}{3}\right\rfloor = 0$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{4}{x}\left\lfloor\frac{x}{3}\right\rfloor= \infty$$